# How to unit test GraphQL queries in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby and Jest for testing. By default Gatsby handles the GraphQL data fetching, and from what I've found it doesn't provide any solution for testing its GraphQL queries in unit tests.

Is there a way to do this? Right now I'm just mocking the queries the test the component itself, but I want to be able to test queries work without manually doing so in GraphiQL.

Here's what my code looks like:

### PageContent.jsx

```jsx
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

const PageContent = ({ data: { markdownRemark: { html } } }) => (
  <div>
    {html}
  </div>
);

PageContent.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    markdownRemark: PropTypes.shape({
      html: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

export const query = graphql`
  query PageContent($id: ID!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { id: $id }) {
      html
    }
  }
`;

export default PageContent;
```

### PageContent.test.jsx

```jsx
import PageContent from 'templates/PageContent';

describe("<PageContent>", () => {
  let mountedComponent;
  let props;

  const getComponent = () => {
    if (!mountedComponent) {
      mountedComponent = shallow(<PageContent {...props} />);
    }
    return mountedComponent;
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    mountedComponent = undefined;
    props = {
      data: {
        markdownRemark: {
          html: '<div>test</div>',
        },
      },
    };
  });

  it("renders a <div> as the root element", () => {
    expect(getComponent().is('div')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("renders `props.data.markdownRemark.html`", () => {
    expect(getComponent().contains(props.data.markdownRemark.html)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko nope sorry. I'm still just mocking the queries

Comment: What do you want to test about the GraphQL query? That it's still the same?

Comment: You could snapshot test it, just check to see what's in the `query` export.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [plugin that enables testing of Gatsby components with GraphQL queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-testing/). If you install it you can retrieve the actual Graph QL data by replacing your mocked data

```
  data: {
        markdownRemark: {
          html: '<div>test</div>',
        },
      }
```

with

```
  data: await getPageQueryData(`/path/to/your/page`)
```

It will then pull the data from the latest time you built your project (using `gatsby build` or `gatsby develop`)

Comment: If you want to test your raw query data (i.e., making sure markdown conforms to standards or matches file structure), then you can make a "test" page that queries for the data to test. Then, `await getPageQueryData('/path/to/your/**test-**page')`